# ServiceStack ORMLite Caching error

Tags: c#, caching, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to implement persistent database caching to SQL using ORMLite. I have enabled ORMLite cache provider in the Configure method in Global.asax.cs:

```
// Implement database caching for request/response JSON
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApiDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));
container.RegisterAs<OrmLiteCacheClient, ICacheClient>();
container.Resolve<ICacheClient>().InitSchema();
```

Here's how I'm implementing the caching, as seen in many examples around the interwebs

```
public object Get(PatientRequest request)
{
    var cacheKey = request.SSN;
    var expireInTimespan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15, 0);
    return base.Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache<Patient>(base.Cache, cacheKey, expireInTimespan, () => {
        var Patient = dbConn.Single<Patient>(x => x.SSN == request.SSN && x.FacilityLocationId == Convert.ToInt32(UALocation));

        if (patient != null)
        {
            dbConn.LoadReferences(patient);
            ...
            return patient;
        }
        else
        {
            var error = new GenericResponse();
            error.Message = "No patient found by SSN.";

            return error;   // This doesn't work...
        }
    });
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error 8 The type arguments for method 'ServiceStack.RequestExtensions.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache<T>(ServiceStack.Web.IRequest, ServiceStack.Caching.ICacheClient, string, System.TimeSpan?, System.Func<T>)' 
cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cache population delegate function must return a result of `T`, as the last argument of `ToOptimzedResultUsingCache<T>` is `System.Func<T>`. As you have not specified `T` and you have no `return` it won't compile.

Try specifying the type of `T` as `Patient` and setting the `return` as shown below:

```cs
var cacheKey = request.SSN;
var expireInTimespan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15, 0);
return base.Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache<Patient>(base.Cache, cacheKey, expireInTimespan, () => {
    var patient = dbConn.Single<Patient>(x => x.SSN == request.SSN && x.FacilityLocationId == Convert.ToInt32(UALocation));
    if(patient == null)
        return null;

    dbConn.LoadReferences(patient);
    ...
    return patient;
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: that does help. However, I need to use the result of the cache response further on in the code. If I just return the value, it works, but if I try to store the value in a variable of type "Patient", I get an error of "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'RxInfoHub_Svc.Patient'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)". I've tried casting the value into a "Patient" type several ways, but it is fixated on being an "object". Help?

Comment: @ItJustWerks Can you post the rest of your code. i.e. the code you use further on, when refer to this `I need to use the result of the cache response further on in the code.`.

Comment: @ItJustWerks You need to do the further processing in the delegate method, and allow that result to be cached. The result from `ToOptimizedResultUsingCache<T>` is of `object` type, not a `Patient` object, hence you will get casting issues if you try to do further processing. *I updated the code.*

Comment: accepting your answer as it does work. I do have another question though: In pretty much all of my classes, I want to return a different type if there is an error. See code updates in my original post. Does the ToOptimizedResultUsingCache method work in that scenario? I get an error about the "GenericResponse" type not being castable as "Patient".

Comment: @ItJustWerks It's not really a good idea to be returning completely different objects for a given request, as that goes away from the RESTful service principals. However, though not recommended, you could change to `ToOptimizedResultUsingCache<object>` allowing you to cache any object and not specifically a `Patient` type. But do you really want to cache an error state? You should consider throwing a custom exception instead, that contains any relevant data.